# It is necessary to limit the ability to resend codes via SMS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to check if the user re-requests sending SMS more than once every 30 seconds, I need to return an error that the action is performed too often and the remaining time until the next send.

The controller itself

```java
@PostMapping("/resend/sms")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasAuthority('SCOPE_trusted')")
public Mono<UserDTO> trustedResendRegistrationSms(
        @Validated @RequestBody RegistrationDTO registrationDTO,) {
    return accountService.resendRegistrationSms(registrationDTO.getLogin());
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what difficulty you're having doing this.

Comment: Basically I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could register user requests by some user fingerprint inside your controller bean, and break the request whenever it comes within 30 seconds or in some extra cases.

Here is my example,

```
package com.example.app.rest;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/request-limited/")
public class RequestLimitedController {

    // Store user request in set inside the bean
    private Set<UserRequest> requests = new HashSet<>();
    private static class UserRequest {
        public String userFingerprint; // we will use user ip as a fingerprint
        public LocalDateTime lastRequestTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        public Long count = 0L; // not used in this example, but you can limit the max number of request from the same ip

        public UserRequest(String userFingerprint) {
            this.userFingerprint = userFingerprint;
        }
    }


    @GetMapping("frequency-sensitive-request")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> processFrequencySensitiveRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {

        // First, remove expired requests from set
        requests = requests.stream()
                .filter( entry -> entry.lastRequestTime.isAfter(LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(1)) )
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        String userFingerprint = httpRequest.getRemoteAddr();

        // Find the last request for this user
        UserRequest userRequest = requests.stream().filter( r -> r.userFingerprint.equals(userFingerprint)).findFirst().orElse(null);
        if (userRequest!=null && userRequest.lastRequestTime.isAfter(LocalDateTime.now().minusSeconds(30))) {
            // if it was within 30 seconds, then throw 403
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).build();
        }
        if (userRequest == null) {
            // If it doesn't exist then create and register it
            userRequest = new UserRequest(userFingerprint);
            requests.add(userRequest);
        }
        // Update count and time
        userRequest.count++;
        userRequest.lastRequestTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        // Process the request here

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

}
```